# Create NLB with 3 targets in cyclic order

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a requirement where i have 9 EC2 instances and want to create 9 NLBs with each NLB having 3 EC2 instances in them in a cyclic order.

Example:

> NLB 1: Targets 1,9,8
>
> NLB 2: Targets 2,1,9
>
> NLB 3: Targets 3,2,1
>
> and so on till
>
> NLB 9: Targets 9,8,7

This is what I have right now for NLB.

```
module "shard-nlb" {
  source  = "../../alb-module/aws"

  count                 = var.shard_count
  load_balancer_type    = "network"
  vpc_id                = var.vpc_id
  subnets               = var.shard_double_subnet_ids[count.index % length(var.shard_subnet_ids)]
  security_groups       = concat(data.aws_security_groups.sg_xyz.ids, data.aws_security_groups.sg_abc.ids)
  target_groups =  [
  {
      name_prefix       = "SHnlb-"
      backend_protocol  = "TCP"
      backend_port      = 5678
      target_type       = "instance"
      preserve_client_ip   = false
      targets = [
      {
          target_id = aws_instance.shard-ec2[count.index].id
          port = 5678
      },
      {
          target_id = aws_instance.shard-ec2[count.index-1].id
          port = 5678
      },
      {
          target_id = aws_instance.shard-ec2[count.index-2].id
          port = 5678
      }
      ]
  }
  ]

  http_tcp_listeners    =  [
  {
        port               = 443
        protocol           = "TCP"
        target_group_index = 0
  }
  ]
  internal              = "internal"
  tags                  = module.label.tags
  name                  = lower("SH-nlb-${count.index+1}")
}
```

With one target as count.index it works but when i add, count.index-1 and count.index-2, it starts giving error:

```
│ Error: Invalid "count" attribute
│ 
│   on shard_infra.tf line 112, in module "shard-nlb":
│  112:           target_id = aws_instance.shard-ec2[count.index-1].id
│ 
│ The "count" object does not have an attribute named "index-1". The only
│ supported attribute is count.index, which is the index of each instance of
│ a resource block that has the "count" argument set.
```

I wanted to something similar to below like following but they also dont work inside module. Gives error "The block type name "locals" is reserved for use by Terraform in a future version."

```
  locals{
    shard1              = "${count.index}"
    shard2              = "${count.index-1 >= 0 ? count.index-1 : var.shard_count-count.index-1}"
    shard3              = "${count.index-2 >= 0 ? count.index-2 : var.shard_count-count.index-2}"
  }
```

Is there any way this cyclic order in NLB can be achieved?

Edit to add EC2 definition:

```
resource "aws_instance" "shard-ec2" {
 count                  = var.shard_count
 ami                    = data.aws_ami.id
 instance_type          = "t3.medium"
 key_name               = var.key_name
 iam_instance_profile   = var.iam_instance_profile
 tags                   = merge(module.label.tags,{"Name" = "shard-${count.index+1}"})
 subnet_id              = var.shard_subnet_ids[count.index % length(var.shard_subnet_ids)]
 ebs_optimized          = true
 vpc_security_group_ids = concat(data.aws_security_groups.sg_xyz.ids, data.aws_security_groups.sg_abc.ids)
 user_data              = templatefile( var.shard_filepath)
 user_data_replace_on_change = false
 root_block_device{
     volume_type = "gp3"
     volume_size = 300
     delete_on_termination = true
     tags = merge(module.label.tags,{"Name" = "shard-${count.index+1}"})
 }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [ tags, tags_all ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `aws_instance.shard-ec2`?

Comment: too long to add here, edited in post.

Comment: The error you report is because you have `count.index-1`, rather then `count.index - 1`.

Comment: Yes, it works when i use: target_id = aws_instance.shard-ec2[count.index - 1].id and target_id = aws_instance.shard-ec2[count.index - 2].id.
but now i get a new error: 
Error: Invalid index, 
│   on shard_infra.tf line 108, in module "shard-nlb":
│  108:           target_id = aws_instance.shard-ec2[count.index - 1].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_instance.shard-ec2 is tuple with 3 elements
│     │ count.index is 0
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a
│ negative number is not a valid index for a sequence.

Comment: I somehow need to update  "count.index - 1" with "var.shard_count - count.index - 1" if its value goes negative.